# How to chain asynchronous operations using Java RX Observable?

Tags: java, rx-java

I want to make a HTTP request repeatedly and act on result. I start with `public Observable<NewsItem> fetchItems(NewsFeed feed)`. One request gets a few news items but I decided to flatten it.

The idea was to use `Observable.interval()` make the request multiple times, then combine resulting Observables into one.

```
       Observable
            .interval(timePerItem, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map(i -> feed)
            .map(feed -> fetchItems(feed))
            .subscribe(result -> System.out.println(result));
```

But the result is `Observable<Observable<NewsItem>>` not `Observable<NewsItem>`. How to marge them?

I have found the marge() operator [(RX-Java doc: Marge)](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables#merge). But it does not seem to fit the use case.

In previous version I used `CompletableFuture<List<NewsItem>> fetchNewsItems()` but I wasn't able to fit it into Observable chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the problem, but aren't you just looking for `flatMap`?

```
Observable
    .interval(timePerItem, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .flatMap(i -> fetchItems(feed))
    .subscribe(result -> System.out.println(result));
```

Comment: Looks like that is what I was looking for. Learning rx-java from https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki is hard. flatMap is not mentioned in the introduction and the way it is described in https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Transforming-Observables#flatmap-concatmap-and-flatmapiterable is strange. Thank you!

Comment: There are many more links to great tutorials at http://reactivex.io/tutorials.html. And if you find a good tutorial which is not yet mentioned there or you wrote one yourself, make a pull request at https://github.com/ReactiveX/reactivex.github.io so that the link is included on that page ;-)